# Setting cookies client side in Golang

Tags: go, cookies, gorilla

Good morning everyone,

I'm trying to build a test web-app with Go, but I can't seem to find a way to properly set the cookies. I'm using the `securecookie` function from gorilla package, and it works when I try it on the same host (while opening a browser to localhost:port I can correctly find the cookie set).

However, if I try with another computer to connect to the host (192.168.x.x.:port) the code works perfectly but the cookie is not set, I cannot find it inspecting the page.

Here's the code:

```
package main

import (
    "net/http"
    "github.com/gorilla/securecookie"
)

// Secure cookie instance used later
var hashKey = []byte(securecookie.GenerateRandomKey(64))
var blockKey = []byte(securecookie.GenerateRandomKey(32))
var s = securecookie.New(hashKey, blockKey)

// Generates a secure cookie, returning the cookie
func GenerateSecureCookie(name, value string) *http.Cookie {
    data := map[string]string{name: value}
    cookie := &http.Cookie{}
    if encoded, err := s.Encode(name, data); err == nil {
        cookie.Name = name
        cookie.Value = encoded
        cookie.Secure = true
        cookie.HttpOnly = true
    } else {
        panic(err)
    }
    return cookie
}


func handlerFunction(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    cookie := GenerateSecureCookie("testcookie", "a random value")

    // Set the cookie
    http.SetCookie(w, cookie)
    w.Write([]byte("Hello world"))
}

func main() {
    mux := http.NewServeMux()
    mux.HandleFunc("/", handlerFunction)

    http.ListenAndServe(":3334", mux)
}
```

Any hint about why this happens?
Thank you!

Comment: In the first case, are you by any chance accessing the server via https://localhost:port (presumably after generating a cert for it)? Be aware that browsers reject attempts by an insecure origin (like `http://192.168.x.x.:port`) to set a cookie marked `Secure`.

Comment: I've not set a cert for this test, I'm still coding everything. However, accessing the server via browser on localhost:port from the same computer where the server is hosted correctly sets the cookies. Meanwhile, trying on another machine on the same network and accessing the server on 192.168.1.112:3332 (the IP of the server host) the service works, but no cookies are set. I will try to remove the secure flag from the cookie to see what happens an update you, thank you for your help!

Comment: That makes sense. I'm guessing your frontend is running on `http://localhost:somePort` and your backend on `http://localhost:someOtherPort`. In that case, those two origins are considered _same-site_, and the browser will accept to set cookies regardless of their SameSite attribute. But because `http://localhost:port` and `http://192.168.1.112:3332` are not considered same-site, that won't work.

Comment: You were perfectly right: removing the secure flag from the cookie makes the cookies correctly set also on the front end of another machine. Now I need a ssl cert also for testing :sigh:. Thank you very much again!

Comment: Great. Good luck!